# Delete Rails Migration But Without Deleting Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

If you delete a model, the migrations are deleted as well.

But is there a way of deleting just the migrations related to a model without deleting the model itself?

Your sincerely

Comment: Rolling back the migrations and deleting the ones in question also delete the model's file?

Comment: I didn't speak of rolling back ! I speak of un-generating migrations related to a certain model. One could define these as all of those migrations that either generated a table for a certain model or changed columns of said table.

Comment: deleting the migration won't delete the models unless you run `rails d model ...`

Comment: Which is why I answered my own question the way I did. But thanks

Answer (score 1):

Migration files are just files and once they are not needed (when you're sure that there's no instance of a database with that old schema that might be needed to migrate up/down) - there's no harm in deleting them.

If by "migrations" you mean model's underlying database table itself - you can rollback the migration that has corresponding `created_table` or have a migration that will `drop_table` and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to delete the migration file, let's say your:

```
migration_file_name = 20181225123240_create_posts.rb
```

Run this command `rails d migration create_posts`

Answer (score 0):

I opt for dropping the table and manually deleting all other related migrations.

```
rails generate migration DropProductsTable
```

and after the migration has been generated as such write the migration

```
class DropProductsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :products
  end
end
```